# No 'Software Update' option in iPad from iOS 4

Tags: ipad, software-update, ios

I'm helping my Dad over the phone to upgrade his iPad. He's a senior, and definitely not tech savvy.

When we go to Settings > General, there is no "Software Update" option. His current version is iOS 4. Where can I find the option to update the software wirelessly on iOS 4.0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

iOS 4 can't be updated over the air. OTA updating was introduced in iOS 5.

To update the iPad to iOS 5, you need to use iTunes. Connect the device to iTunes and it should prompt that a new version of iOS is available and allow the device to be updated.

Then, in the future, the device can be updated using Software Update from settings.